# When using demo api in CopyLeaks GOT error Value cannot be null. (Parameter ''end' time is missing')'end'

Tags: copyleaks-api

Running this command

```
curl -XGET -H "Authorization: Bearer My-Login-Token-Access" https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/usages/history?start=01-09-2023&end=31-09-2023
```

Value cannot be null. (Parameter ''end' time is missing')'end' is not recognized as an internal or external command

while url params is correct still not detect on api copyleaks, so i cant use api for show scan history in COPYLEKASS for plagiat checker. Is any body have same issue?

Running this command on post man and terminal through CURL function

```
curl -XGET -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXX" https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/usages/history?start=01-09-2023&end=31-09-2023
```

I'm expecting result of this command, like csv or another result report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you mentioned happen because your `end` date is in the further. Try to have an `end` date that is today or in the past.

Like this command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ABC123" "https://api.copyleaks.com/v3/scans/usages/history?start=01-09-2023&end=31-09-2023"
```